# Can't connect to server until reboot computers

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, mappeddrive, database-connection

I have a domain with around 90 PC with the domain controller running by Windows Server 2012 R2 and the PCs Windows 7. Every PC has a mapped drive from the server and a database interface that's linked to the database in the server. Everything was working perfectly until a couple days ago when one PC couldn't reach the server (mapped drive is disconnected and database access couldn't be reached)

I checked the PCs connection to the network and it was able to reach other PCs and surf the internet with no problems. So I restarted the PC and that problem was fixed. The day after, almost every PC in the domain had the same problem. And restarting the PC always fixes the problem (Some PCs will reconnect to server after 2 to 3 attempts of restarts)

I tried restarting the server but that just made all PCs that were reconnected by restarting to lose connection again..

If you know anything about this problem please advice..